# Why god choose earth for life, why not others?

Tags: scripture, creation

I want to know that why god choose earth for life and why not other planet. He is god after all and could have choose to create organism which can sustain as life in other planets the. Why only earth why not others?

Comment: There is life on others planets/suns etc. For example Surya lives with his family on the sun.

Comment: Not a convincing argument.

Comment: What do you mean by  not convincing? Please explain? It states clearly in the scriptures that other planets are inhabitated by other devas/devis and their families.

Comment: no life found on other planets.

Comment: I do not understand. Again, there is life on other planets according to the scriptures. What more do you want?

Comment: So are you satisfied with my answer?